# How to run T-SQL queries using LINQ to Entities?

Tags: .net, sql, t-sql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I want to execute some T-SQL. I want to use existing L2E connection configurations, I don't want to add a new SqlClient provider connection configuration to my .config file. How do I do that? ObjectContext seems to have only methods that return results with classes from data mapping schema.

I've tried doing ObjectContext.Connection.CreateCommand method, then specifying my T-SQL as the command text, but it failed with a message that is something like "could not understand what entities you are talking about in your query".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`ExecuteStoreQuery()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487208.aspx). Also see [How to: Directly Execute Commands Against the Data Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358769.aspx)